# ConstraintWidth_percent doesn't work propely

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to make layout with two text fields, which will have 40/60 ratio (like on image below) throw contraint. I can see result on preview on layout in Android Studio (see the image below), but when I start my app, the string becomes invisible, like contraint doesn't work. But if I will but istead of 0dp wrap_conent, both textViews becomes visible, but text with wrap_content has width more, then 0.4 or 0.6. How to fix this? Or maybe there is another way to impelement this?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:text="LeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeft" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/value"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            tools:text="RightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRight" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: *enter image description here*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the constraints from your guideline, remove the `layout_constraintWidth_percent` from your textviews and instead constrain them on your guideline, while dding the appropriate start and end constraints as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline"
        tools:text="LeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeft" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:text="RightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRight" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It's still doesn't works for some reason. Maybe the problem in 0dp?

Comment: @Strangelove I edited my answer to remove constraints from the guideline as well. It works on my device now. What do you see in yours?

Comment: I figured out. My layout - item in recyclerView. And my rv had wrap_content. After putting match_parent, all works

Comment: @Strangelove glad you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:paddingBottom="8dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/name"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
    tools:text="LeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeft" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/name"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
    tools:text="RightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRight" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added 2 more constraints, check this answer and see if this will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.4"
        tools:text="LeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeftLeft" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6"
        tools:text="RightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRightRight" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```